# use grep to find a word in the output from telnet connection

Tags: linux, grep, telnet

I would like to use telnet to connect to a system and check if `foreign` is in the response.

I am trying ...

`echo quit | telnet 192.0.0.1 443 | grep -q "foreign"`

In that a successful connection means "foreign" was found in the string. This is because in the output I get something like...

```
Trying 192.0.0.1
Connected to 192.0.0.1
Connection closed by foreign host
```

But if I check `echo $?` I get a `1` indicating it failed to find the word. My guess is that this is due to the multiple line output.

Is there a way to handle this so I get `0` from `echo $?`?

Must be done via terminal - no scripts etc.

And must be `telnet`

Comment: That message is probably written to stderr, not stdout.

Comment: `netcat` is a better tool for testing network network connections than `telnet`.

Comment: Telnet is the only option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do:

```
{ sleep 1; echo quit; } | telnet 192.0.0.1 443 2>&1 | grep -q "foreign"
```

or with `bash`:

```
{ sleep 1; echo quit; } | telnet 192.0.0.1 443 |& grep -q "foreign"
```

With retry:

```
until [[ $out == *foreign* ]]; do
    out=$({ sleep 1; echo quit; } | telnet 192.0.0.1 443 |& grep "foreign")
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Will give that a try - thanks!

Comment: Added loop way.

Comment: thanks! I realized I had an issue with syntax so the first may work but helpful to have the loop too in case it's necessary.